# Can Anyone Identify This Insect?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image: insect]

I keep seeing these bugs on a wall in my house in Istanbul (Turkey) walking up and down generally during evening and night. They are about 1 mm long and have a brownish color. I see more of them through late hours. Does anyone know what they are called?

Comment: I don't recognize it, but it might be possible to identify this insect using an [automated species identification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_species_identification) program.

Comment: Related: [Bug Identification: Tiny Bugs in Fairport NY](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/85322), [What are these tiny, swarming, jumping bugs?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/80343), [Help identifying tiny jumping bug](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/74215), [Taxonomy: Categorising Collembola](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/54878), [What kind of small insect is this?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/16645), [Unknown aquatic larvae](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/72644)

Answer (score 2):

Those are collembolans. Common name, springtails. Do you have a potted plant nearby? They are completely harmless.

Here is an example:

[image]
(picture from [bugguide.net](https://bugguide.net/node/view/104064)

Comment: Could you please add, _why_  you think these are collembolans?

Comment: SIze and shape. See https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/54878/taxonomy-categorising-collembola

Comment: Agreed. The picture is poor but it looks very much like a typical springtail