# Unknown aquatic larvae

Tags: species-identification, entomology

These critters have taken up residence in standing water in a small terrarium. It is home to several frogs and lizards. If they will coexist peacefully, I have no objection. If they will harm plants or critters I'll have to evict them.[image]

Comment: Related: [Bug Identification: Tiny Bugs in Fairport NY](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/85322), [What are these tiny, swarming, jumping bugs?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/80343), [Help identifying tiny jumping bug](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/74215), [Can Anyone Identify This Insect?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/72041), [Taxonomy: Categorising Collembola](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/54878), [What kind of small insect is this?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/16645)

Answer (score 3):

Those are collembolans. The common name is "springtail". Several groups of collembola are semi-aquatic. They are not larvae, but adults. There is a nice paper on aquatic collembolans here: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4020-8259-7_36

Comment: Not harmful at all.