# Help identifying tiny jumping bug

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I've found a few of these bugs hanging out on my desk. There aren't many. Maybe 5-10 at any given time. Are they a type of springtail? I couldn't find an image in searching that made me say, "That's it!"

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!
[image: bug]

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Could you edit your question to include a location? It may help with the identification.

Comment: Related to: [Bug Identification: Tiny Bugs in Fairport NY](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/85322), [What are these tiny, swarming, jumping bugs?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/80343), [Can Anyone Identify This Insect?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/72041), [Taxonomy: Categorising Collembola](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/54878), [What kind of small insect is this?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/16645), [Unknown aquatic larvae](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/72644)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are springtails. Order Collembola. You can find yours here on BugGuide. https://bugguide.net/node/view/258362

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Now to figure out how to get rid of them! :-)

Comment: @Mattaton do you have a plant that you water frequently nearby your desk? They probably come from that. They're not harmful and if it really annoys you, just water less frequently.

Comment: @tox123 Nope, no plant and no moisture that I can find. My office is in a basement, but there's no noticeable humidity. Might see about getting a dehumidifier, just in case. Not really sure WHY they're hanging out here.

Comment: @Mattaton they might just be lost. They live in soil and dark conditions, so it's possible that there may just be a way into your basement from surrounding soil.